# Count Records with in Clause , may add where condition

Tags: mysql

I want to count all items with in Clause

like i have a following Query

```
SELECT `vote` from `tablename` where `vote_id` in (1,2,3,4);
```

I dont have an idea how to count items for  each record in above query .

Can anybody tell me how to do that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? Perhaps by providing an example output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `count()` function in sql to count the no. of rows

```
SELECT COUNT(`vote`) as votesno from `tablename` where `vote_id` in (1,2,3,4) GROUP BY votesno;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count the rows for each id you have in your `IN` clause just count the records grouping by `vote_id`:

```
SELECT COUNT(`vote`) as votes 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE `vote_id` IN (1,2,3,4) 
GROUP BY `vote_id`;
```

Answer (score 2):

for total counts

```
SELECT count(`vote`) from `tablename` where `vote_id` in (1,2,3,4);
```

and for individual count

```
SELECT `vote_id`,count(`vote`) from `tablename` where `vote_id` in (1,2,3,4) group by `vote_id`;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT vote_id,count(vote) from tablename where vote_id in (1,2,3,4) GROUP BY vote_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(vote_id)
from `tablename`
 where `vote_id`in (1,2,3,4);
```